# Problems deploying Grails application on cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I'm new cloudbees user, I've succeeded in building my war file but I can't deploy it because when a I'm going to use `Deploy Now` option, putting my application ID **claxon/claxon** I always get the same error:

```
**"hudson.util.IOException2: Server.InternalError - Expected Application ID format: account/appname > claxon/"**
```

this is the log..

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Server.InternalError - Expected Application ID format: account/appname > claxon/
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable.deployFile(Deployable.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployNowRunAction$Deployer.perform(DeployNowRunAction.java:639)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployNowRunAction.run(DeployNowRunAction.java:484)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployNowTask$ExecutableImpl.run(DeployNowTask.java:157)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: Server.InternalError - Expected Application ID format: account/appname > claxon/
    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.readResponse(BeesClient.java:850)
    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.applicationDeployArchive(BeesClient.java:435)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable.deployFile(Deployable.java:124)
    ... 5 more
Duration: 4.1 sec
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anybody can help me?.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the `claxon/` the account is sorted for you when you choose the account from the account drop down. just put the id part.

If you expand the help text you will see that it says not to prefix:

[image: Using my SuperUser rights I took this screenshot from your account]

Note: I used my superuser rights to capture this screenshot... the only bit that might be confidential is your account name, which you had already exposed via the original question.

Comment: it's worked!! ;) thank you very much, I've just created a new application and it works properly following your advice ;).

Comment: You might want to accept the answer then, since it will improve your StackOverflow stats